# Error on Android Studio: Program type already present: android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

when I put multiDexEnabled true, it keeps showing the above error. After I deleted multiDexEnabled true, the above error is gone, but got another error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$2.
Pls help.

Comment: Please show your gradle

Comment: Would you please check the dependencies by "./gradlew app:dependencies" and exclude duplicates

Comment: My gradle is too long. Can't paste it here as it exceeds number of characters. Can you tell me how I can attach screenshot here? Or any other method?